# SQLite3 incorrect number of bindings on second query

Tags: python, sqlite, binding

Using Python and SQlite3 where c is a cursor this code...

```
        print("vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv")
        print("SQL and parameters:",sql,parm)
        c.execute(sql,parm)
        # Get the row
        print("Executed OK")
        response = c.fetchone()
        # If not successful return null
        if not response:
            return None
        #
        print("and produced ", response)
        print("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
```

give this output:

```
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
SQL and parameters: select * from Links where LinkNum = ? (301,)
Executed OK
and produced  (301, 'Index', 'The Independent', 'https://www.independent.co.uk/', 6, 0)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
SQL and parameters: select * from Links where LinkNum = ? (301,)
Encountered exception of type ProgrammingError with arguments ('Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied.',)

The application will close
```

Two identical statements. 1 works and the next throws the exception. As can be seen the row I'm trying to retrieve has 6 columns but that's the only hint/clue I can see. Can anyone help with tracking down the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please include the definitions for `sql` and `parm`.

Comment: Er.... sql is a string containing "select * from Links where LinkNum = ?" and parm is a tuple (301,)

Comment: Then this code cannot be generating the error message you quote in your question.

Comment: Well the evidence is there, I had a think about this. The code is in a framework I'm developing. The sql is built thus:

     print(type(mdl.__class__.__name__))
     sql =  "select * from " + mdl.__class__.__name__ + " where "

Comment: Sorry hit enter...

Well the evidence is there, The code is in a framework I'm developing. The sql is built thus:

     print(type(mdl.__class__.__name__))
     sql =  "select * from " + mdl.__class__.__name__ + " where "

followed by adding the primary key(s) name. The first result is used to instantiate a Links object. This code is in an ancestor class and the dataclasses are self-instantiating. The second call occurs inside that object. I thought the Links object might be going into the sql. With the print the name is <class 'str'> in both calls so the sql is definitely a string.

Comment: That's not what I am asking about.  I am pointing out that your error message is not consistent with the code you posted above.

Comment: Consistent or not the evidence is there. Are you able to offer any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever was causing SQLite to have a fit I remedied the problem by retrieving the second row/object out side the Links object and passing it as an argument to the method I was calling, rather than have that method attempt to retrieve the object.

The problem would still be there but must be deep within the internals of Python instantiation and/or SQLite. Whatever, this problem is solved with some less fancy code.